# Svelte - how to make data not reactive?

Tags: javascript, svelte

I have some HTML elements that have a property `color`.

```
<label name={name} style="color: {color}"); ">{name}</label>
```

The value of `color` will change over time. And I will add more of these `label` elements in future, but I wish **only new elements inherit the new value** - effectively, I wish to disable reactivity for this variable.

Is this possible in Svelte?

Comment: How are you setting the `color` variable?

Comment: So you are saying that you will have multiple labels, each with a name acting as their unique key? You could save the current color to a dictionary indexed by name at the time of the label creation. Then access the required color with:


`<label name={name} style="color: {labelColors[name]}"); ">{name}</label>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a property labelColor and use it, then when the color property changes it wont affect labelColor.

Comment: Makes sense, pass via value.